# Field is not visible but test passes

Tags: android-espresso

Here Espresso's test that check that textView  - `walletLabelTextView` is displayed:

```
onView(withId(tradersRecyclerView))
            .perform(scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(traderRandomPos));
    onView(withRecyclerView(tradersRecyclerView).atPositionOnView(traderRandomPos, walletLabelTextView))
            .check(matches(withText("Wallet:")))
```

Here screenshot:

[image]

As result test is pass. Because view **Wallet:** is visible. Nice.

Now I increase font size (huge).
Here screenshot:
[image]

As you can see the view **Wallet:** now is not visible. But test again success pass.
Why?

Comment: `withText()` only checks if the text is matching, and maybe your adapter only updates the visibility of the item. If you wanted to check if it was also displayed, you could do `allOf(withText("Wallet:"), isDisplayed())`.

Comment: @Aaron Not help. Same result. Test is pass. onView(withRecyclerView(tradersRecyclerView)
                .atPositionOnView(traderRandomPos, walletLabelTextView))
                .check(matches(allOf(withText("Wallet:"), isDisplayed())))